# Create Activity Indicator with C #

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Is it possible to create an activity indicator without using XAML? I have a view already ready in .cs and I did not want to have to recreate it.

Comment: What do you mean without XAML. What kind of view do you already have? Are you developing with WPF or UWP?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to describe it. I'm making a cross-platform app using xamarin.forms (for Android, iOS and UWP). I don't know if it's the right one, but I'm creating my views based on C #.

Comment: Yes, anything you can do in XAML you should be able to do in C#.  You would just add it to the layout you've created in C# and then trigger it when appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create every control that you can create via XAML from code, too. Please see the following example

```
class MyView : ContentView
{
    AbsoluteLayout _layout;
    ActivityIndicator _activityIndicator;

    void InitializeControls()
    {
        _layout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        this.Content = _layout;

        // ...

        _activityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator();
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(_activityIndicator, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(_activityIndicator, new Rectangle(.5,.5,-1,-1));
        _layout.Children.Add(_activityIndicator);
    }

    async void UpdateData()
    {
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        this.Data = GetData();
        _activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

In `InitializeControls` we are first initializing a layout (an `AbsoluteLayout` in this case) and later create a new `ActivityIndicator`. We are setting `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` with the `AbsoluteLayout.Set...` methods (these are setters for attached properties, see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties/)). Last we add the `ActivityIndicator` to the `AbsoluteLayout`.

The `UpdateData` method is a made-up method to show how to use the `ActivityIndicator` when updating the data of the view. We first set `IsRunning` on the `ActivityIndicator` to show it, then fetch the data and last unset `IsRunning` to hide the `Activity